# DefaultKeywordsTermStore VS DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore

Tags: managed-metadata, taxonomy, term-store

What is the difference between the two properties `DefaultKeywordsTermStore` VS `DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore` In the code below what will be the difference in `termStore` variable in both cases below:

Case 1

```
TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);
TermStore termStore = session.DefaultKeywordsTermStore;
```

Case 2

```
TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);
TermStore termStore = session.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DefaultKeywordsTermStore` is a global term store that contains enterprise keywords.

The `DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore` is a term store that has metadata local to the site collection.

Here is the MSDN [documentation on the TaxonomySession class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomysession_members.aspx) which defines those two properties of the `TaxonomySession` object.

Here is the MSDN general [overview of Managed Metadata in SP 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424402.aspx) which describes the difference between managed terms and keywords.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Dylan's answer following are the UI settings which affects setting of this properties:

`DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore` Maps to the default proxy of Managed Metadata service. If there are multiple proxies,only one proxy has to be designated as default else this property will return NULL

`DefaultKeywordsTermStore` maps to the configuration check box `"This service application is the default storage location for Keywords"` If this option is not selected for any one of the proxy or more than one proxy, it will return NULL

In below image, first check box refers to `DefaultKeywordsTermStore` and second refers to `DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore` 
[image]